# Android Pop Up during opening of Application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-popupwindow

I am developing an Android application, where I need to show a popup containing some message on application opening (Image attached for reference).
I have tried to achieve this using toast message and snack bar but could not do exact same.

Please suggest which component in Android to be used to achieve this functionality?

[image: Here is the ScreenShot]

Comment: You can use bottomsheet dialogue.

Comment: you can refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Comment: why every one giving down vote, may be you are very intelligent , please give or suggest answer or don't waste your time to down vote

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired results using a `dialog`. I am sharing the code, you can modify it as you want but make sure you put it inside the `onCreate method` of the `launcher activity`.

This is the code for a simple `dialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Look at this dialog!")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //do things
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

The one shown in the picture shared by you is a `custom dialog` where you have to make your own layout. Here is an example,

**1. Create your own layout**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffffff">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#DA5F6A"
    android:src="@drawable/dialog_cross"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/text_dialog"
    android:layout_below="@+id/a"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_dialog"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_red_selector"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**2. Create a `class` for the `custom dialog`**

```
public class ViewDialog {

public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
    text.setText(msg);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
}
```

**3. Make an `object` in your `launcher activity` of the custom dialog class and call the function `showDialog`**

```
ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
alert.showDialog(getActivity(), "Thank you for installing the Paytm 
App");
```

Or you could use an [external library](https://github.com/00ec454/pop) for getting the desired results

`Pop.on(this).with().title(R.string.title).layout(R.layout.custom_pop).show();`

where `R.layout.custom_pop` is the custom layout of your dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for same result:

**dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="X" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Hello, this is your message"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**code:**

```
private void showDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

    wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```